# python sqlite3 for loop update

Tags: python

```
import sqlite3    
conn = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')    
cursor = conn.cursor()    
data = cursor.execute('''SELECT * From Table''')

for i in data:    
    title = i[0]        
    status = i[1]    
    cursor.execute('''UPDATED Table SET status=? WHERE title=?''', (status, title))

cursor.close()    
conn.commit()
```

I am trying to update over multiple iterations.  However, the script breaks out of the loop as soon as the database makes the first update.  How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: "However, the script breaks out of the loop as soon as the database makes the first update." Are you sure your code even makes one update? The syntax is wrong.

Comment: This kind of operation is not idiomatic sql.  It's likely that you can rewrite this into a single statement, no for-loop, for much better performance.  Can you tell us a little more about the query you're doing, we could give you a *much* better answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `data = data.fetchall()` before your loop. Otherwise you wind up recycling the cursor inside of your loop (resetting its result set) while you're trying to loop over that result set.

Using `.fetchall()` returns a list of results so that you have them stored locally before you re-use the cursor.

Alternatively, create a separate cursor to use for your update statements if you don't want to cache the results of the first query locally.