# For-loop exiting prematurely

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm having an issue where a python `for` loop is exiting prematurely. The loop iterates over SQL database entries by location.

If location is found, it will grab the IP address of those entries and send a configuration. If the job fails, or throws an exception in my case, within the exception it will go to a function to update the status, date/time. The expected result currently is an exception.

When it comes back to the original function, it exits the loop and doesn't go to the next DB entry (which I know is there.) If I remove the function from within the exception then everything works fine.

Current results. It shows the loop working from function to function. I should see twice, or 6 lines:

```
Return to Function,
Back to function,
Finished,

Return to Function,
Back to function,
Finished,
```

---

Here's what I'm getting

```
1. IP
2. Status
3. Location
4. Main

Selection: 3


Location: Test

Return to Function,
Back to function,
Finished,
```

Code shown below:

```py
def db_entry(Device, status):

    int = 0

    while int < 1:

        c.execute('SELECT * FROM Automation WHERE Device=?', (Device,))

        if bool(c.fetchone()) == True:
            c.execute("UPDATE Automation SET Time=?, DateTime=?, Status=? WHERE Device=?"(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S +0000"), date.today(), status, Device))
            mydb.commit()
            int = int + 1
        else:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO Automation VALUES ('%s','NETCONF','POC', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (Device, status, date.today(), time.strftime("%H:%M:%S +0000")))
            mydb.commit()
            int = int + 1
    else:
        print("Return to Function")

def send_single_configuration(file):

    status_1 = "Success"
    status_2 = "Fail"

    print("\n")
    view_database()
    print("\n")
    retries = 0

    print("1. IP")
    print("2. Status")
    print("3. Location")
    print("4. Main")
    print("\n")



    input_selection = input("Selection: ")
    print("\n")


    if input_selection == "3":

        location = input("Location: ")

        for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM Automation WHERE Location=?', (location, )):
            try:
                m = manager.connect(row[0], 830, "cisco", "cisco", {'name': 'csr'})
                config_file = open(file=file).read()
                m.edit_config(config_file, target="running")
                db_entry(row[0], status_1)
                print("\n")
                print("Configuration Complete!")
                print("\n")

            except AttributeError:
                db_entry(row[0], status_2)
                print("Back to function")

        else:
            print("Finished")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chris.oberdalhoff/PycharmProjects/Automation/venv/SQL.py", line 412, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/chris.oberdalhoff/PycharmProjects/Automation/venv/SQL.py", line 82, in main
    snmp_configuration()
  File "C:/Users/chris.oberdalhoff/PycharmProjects/Automation/venv/SQL.py", line 326, in snmp_configuration
    send_single_configuration(SNMP_file)
  File "C:/Users/chris.oberdalhoff/PycharmProjects/Automation/venv/SQL.py", line 395, in send_single_configuration
    m.edit_config(config_file, target="running")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit_config'
```

---

More Testing:

If i remove everything but a print statement from the db_entry function which gave the expected result.

I'm thinking something withing this line of code or something with the module/progam interaction.

```
    c.execute("UPDATE Automation SET Time=?, DateTime=?, Status=? WHERE 
    Device=?",(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S +0000"), date.today(), status, 
    Device))
```

Comment: What is the exact AttributeError occuring?

Comment: `status` seems not to be defined, that might make the try-block failing: `db_entry(row[0], status)`.

Comment: Sorry, the status should be status_1. I've changed  this in my code but it still doesn't work

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit_config' - This is happening because m failed, or the connection to the device failed. Currently that is expected

Comment: Instead of using `try/except`, why not just do `if m:`?

Comment: As a side note, the code in the try block should be the bare minimum. As it stands, there are a whole lot of lines that could be raising an AttributeError.

Comment: As mentioned before, I know why I'm getting the Attribute error and it's expected. Its because m is failing which means the connection to the device is failing, in-turn throws the exception and writes it to the DB entry.

Comment: I tried the `if m:` and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the sqlite3 module. I found an old answer from 8 years ago here, [python sqlite3 for loop update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404988/python-sqlite3-for-loop-update).

sqllitle3 module doesn't allow for multi-threading.

I created another connection object and used it to update the DB entry

```
    c = mydb.cursor() # Find the location
    d = mydb.cursor() # Update the entry

            for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM Automation WHERE Location=?', (location, )):
        try:

            device_connect(row[0])
            for capability in m.server_capabilities:
                continue

            d.execute("UPDATE Automation SET Time=?, DateTime=?, Status=? WHERE Device=?",(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S +00"), date.today(), status_1, row[0],))
            mydb.commit()

        except AttributeError:
            d.execute("UPDATE Automation SET Time=?, DateTime=?, Status=? WHERE Device=?",(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S +00"), date.today(), status_2, row[0],))
```